# Getting an invalid response from the ConnectWise API when using multipart/form-data POST request

Tags: php, curl

I am getting an error when using the ConnectWise API to upload a document to an existing ticket, and I believe the issue is with how I performing the curl request.

I have tried messing around with the curl options based on what I've found on Google, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the POST request

```
 function post_ticket_attachment ( $ticket_id, $file_attachment ) {
     $url = "https://api-na.myconnectwise.net/v4_6_release/apis/3.0/system/documents";
     $filename = $file_attachment['name'];
     $filedata = $file_attachment['tmp_name'];
     $filesize = $file_attachment['size'];


     $fields = array ( 
        "recordId" => $ticket_id, 
        "recordType" => "Ticket",
        "title" => $file_attachment['name']
     );

     $filenames = array($filedata);
     $files = array();
     foreach( $filenames as $f ){
         $files[$f] = file_get_contents($f);
     }

     $ch = curl_init();
     $boundary = uniqid();
     $delimiter = '-------------' . $boundary;

     $post_data = build_data_files($boundary, $fields, $files);

     curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => $url,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POST => 1,
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_data,
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: basic " . $connect_wise_auth,
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=" . $delimiter,
        "Content-Length: " . strlen($post_data)
      ),
     ));

     $response = curl_exec($ch);
     console_log ($response);
}
```

And here is how I'm building the post data:

```
function build_data_files($boundary, $fields, $files){
    $data = '';
    $eol = "\r\n";

    $delimiter = '-------------' . $boundary;

    foreach ($fields as $name => $content) {
        $data .= "--" . $delimiter . $eol
            . 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $name . "\"".$eol.$eol
            . $content . $eol;
    }


    foreach ($files as $name => $content) {
        $data .= "--" . $delimiter . $eol
            . 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="' . $name . '"; filename="' . $name . '"' . $eol
            . 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary'.$eol
            ;

        $data .= $eol;
        $data .= $content . $eol;
    }
    $data .= "--" . $delimiter . "--".$eol;


    return $data;
}
```

I'm expecting the request to post correctly, but instead I'm getting a response from ConnectWise stating, "Cannot route. Codebase/company is invalid."

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem and was because I forget to add the username and password to the basic authorization. Looks like that you are adding it but I can't see the what is containing so, just to clarify, the username is the company+publickey and the password is the private key, while encoded in base64.

From [the official documentation](https://developer.connectwise.com/Products/Manage/Developer_Guide) (you may be to login in to be able to see it)

> It is recommended to create API Members versus using API Keys tied to
>   a specific member. Authorization: Basic
>   base64(companyid+publickey:privatekey) (Authorization: Basic
>   Y29tcGFueWlkK3B1YmxpY2tleTpwcml2YXRla2V5)

Once you add that information properly the API will be able to check that your user is correct and you belong to that company.

Please note that this is a very specific problem with a very specific API, so probably if you find more problems in the future you will have more luck asking directly on their forums.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not a full answer (I cannot comment yet)
I was getting this same error when trying to lookup a company by its identifier. It turned out that I was not using the correct URI.
try using fiddler or something to examine exactly what you are posting to see if there is something not 100% right.

My issue was I had a forward slash here: `company/companies/?conditions`

It should have been `company/companies?conditions`

I didn't notice at first as I was using variables to build the URI so it was not very clear.

I also find that using this https://github.com/christaylorcodes/ConnectWiseManageAPI is helpful as I can see how the request should be formatted (by watching with fiddler when I post). Then you can make sure your post is behaving the same.